# How secure is a "root" password that's 26 alphanumeric characters long?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, password, root

I was playing around with a DigitalOcean droplet. Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

I had a `root` password about 8 alphanumeric characters long. Port 22. It would take about 3 days for hackers with Chinese IP addresses to break into it.

I replicated this experiment a couple of times. And each time it took about 3 days.

So I stopped using a password and switched to SSH keys.

DigitalOcean generates an initial `root` password that's 26 alphanumeric characters long. Is that much more secure? (After the first log-in DigitalOcean requires you to choose your own password, so I would choose shorter passwords of 8 characters so I could memorize them.)

Your thoughts on how long would it take hackers to brute force it?

Comment: I don't know How Long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question and testing of the hackers with the Chinese IP!

I'll assume that by 'alphanumeric', you mean `[A-Za-z0-9]`, or 62 characters. If they average 3 days to crack an 8-character password, then it should take 6 days to cover all of the 62^8 possible passwords, so they're able to guess 62^8 ÷ (6×24×60×60) = 421180759 passwords per second.

A 26-character password at that same rate would take 62^26 ÷ 2 ÷ 421180759 ÷ (60×60×24×365), or **1.5 [nonillion](https://www.thoughtco.com/zeros-in-million-billion-trillion-2312346) years to break**, on average.

That said, 421180759 passwords per second is really impressive. I'm guessing your 8-character passwords are not truly random, but rather made up of dictionary words or other semi-predictable components, thus making our guesses-per-second calculation off. They probably can't break the 26-character password in 1.5 nonillion years.

By the way, password strength is often measured in [bits of entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). The 8-character password is log₂(62^8), or 48 bits of entropy, assuming it's truly random. The 26-character password comes in at a whoppping 155 bits of entropy! If you haven't seen it, you also must read the classic [xkcd password strength commic](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: Thank you for the great answer that clarifies the issue for me. You're right, my password was a dictionary word.